# Let, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$. If $A$ is hermitian, then so is $e^{A}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Since $A$ is hermitian we have that $A$ is unitary diagonalizable; as in, there exists matrices $S,D \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that:
$$A = SDS^{*},$$
where $S$ is unitary and $D$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of the eigenvalues of $A$. We have that,
$$e^{A} = Se^{D}S^{*} = S\textrm{diag}(e^{d_1},\dots,e^{d_n})S^{*}.$$
Thus,
$$(e^{A})^* = e^{A},$$
since the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix are real, we have that: $\overline{e^{d_i}} = e^{d_i}.$ Hence, the conclusion follows. Any issues in my proof? Thank you!

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me, but I think a simpler proof is to show that $(e^A)^\ast=e^{A^\ast}$ using the power series expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: An overkill would be to use (holomorphic) functional calculus, and the fact that $e^x\in\mathbb R$ whenever $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did looks good. I would just add the following element

$$\left(e^A\right)^*=\left(S e^D S^*\right)^*=S\left(e^D\right)^*S^*$$
Because $S$ is supposed to be unitary.

Comment: I assumed that the word "Unitarian" was an auto-complete problem, changed it to "unitary". If you actually intended Unitarian, maybe as a joke(???), feel free to change it back...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich... :) After all, the accepted phrase was/is "Weyl's unitarian trick"... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Fair enough - there's plenty of precedent for the word "unitarian" here. I didn't know that, thx. (But I still say "Unitarian" is wrong...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich... :)  Yes, at least by this year, it doesn't make sense. :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes it was auto-complete on iPad. Which by the way seems more religious than mathematician’s…